# grabbing title with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to grab the "title" on the `<li>` when it is clicked. It keeps returning undefined.

html

```
<div id="sidebar">
        <div class="navigation">
  <ul>

    <li title="../../000_Movies/_assets/playlist.html">فیلم ها</li>

  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

js

```
$('.navigation li').click(function () {
$('.slider').animate({
    marginLeft: 0
}, 500,function() {
var test = $(this).attr('title');
alert(test);
  location.href = '';
});
});
```

Comment: Try `.prop("title")` instead of `.attr("title")` but I think it should work anyway ...

Comment: Are you positive that "this" is actually the "li" element? Perhaps try console logging it?

Comment: Can you show us the context of `$(this)` ?

Comment: Seems to work fine - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/d5CPk/

Comment: Try adding `alert(this.tagName)` to find out what tag you are currently working on. If it's not `LI`, then you have a problem with your event handler and we need to see more code. If it is, then you have something else interfering and we need to see more code.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/ulusuv Very strange title, though.

Comment: That should work, have you confirmed that the $(this) in that context is actually referring to the li element?

Comment: Can you paste the complete event code?

Comment: im a idiot. i didnt give you guys enough information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work?

```
$('li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

"this" maybe is not the li.  Or the browser have a bug (IE?). Your code seems correct to me.

Comment: its doing this in FF and chrome

Answer (score 1):

You should create a closure on the clicked `li` element. You're getting `this` inside another function in the click handler function, so the definition of `this` will be different than the original function.

```
$('.navigation li').click(function () {
    // cache the element here
    var that = $(this);

    $('.slider').animate({
        marginLeft: 0
    }, 500, function() {

        // then access that instead here
        // (we're creating a closure on the that variable)
        var test = that.attr('title');
        alert(test);
        location.href = '';
    });
});
```

If you have two nested functions, their `this` variables will be different:

```
function foo () {
    // this here ...
    function bar () {
        // ... is different from this here
    }
}
```

So building on that...

```
$('li').click(function () {
    // $(this) here ...
    $('something').slider({},100, function () {
        // ... is different from $(this) here

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li").on('click',function () {alert($(this).attr('title');)});
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you attaching the click handler on the `li` element? Are you sure `this` inside the handler is poiting to `li` element.

I would try to log `this` and find out what it points to.

If `this` points to `li` then `$(this).attr('title')` should work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it would be:

```
$("li.clickMe").click(function () {
    $("this").attr("title").whateverYouNeedToDo("");
});
```